# Failing EOSIO manual build, Could NOT find WASM (missing: WASM_CLANG WASM_LLC WASM_LLVM_LINK)

Tags: eosio-code, cmake

I tried to follow instruction from https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/manually-build for manual build but kept failing the cmake step.

```
cmake -DBINARYEN_BIN=~/binaryen/bin -DWASM_ROOT=~/wasm-compiler/llvm -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true ..
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
  CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is explicitly set to /usr/local.  This is not
  recommended.


-- Using custom FindBoost.cmake
CMake Error at libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.62.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.67 (or
  newer).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:96 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring EOSIO on Linux
-- binaryen building with -std=c++11
-- binaryen building for platform x86-64
-- binaryen building with -Wall
-- binaryen building with -Werror
-- binaryen building with -Wextra
-- binaryen building with -Wno-unused-parameter
-- binaryen building with -fno-omit-frame-pointer
-- binaryen building with -fPIC
-- binaryen building with -O2
-- binaryen building with -UNDEBUG
-- Using 'SYS' as CORE symbol name
-- Using 'EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV' as public key for 'eosio' account
-- Could NOT find WASM (missing:  WASM_CLANG WASM_LLC WASM_LLVM_LINK)
CMake Error at CMakeModules/wasm.cmake:8 (message):
  No WASM compiler cound be found (make sure WASM_ROOT is set)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:209 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/admin/eos/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/admin/eos/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Is this a known issue and could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've built side chains of EOS and successfully deployed genesis/peer nodes; your logs are instructions for configuring the required machine environment.

Reading the log snippet, we can discern that the build failed because of 2 errors:

1. Incorrect Boost version (1.62 instead of 1.67)
2. Absent WASM compiler (now LLVM compiler 4.0+)

I would also consider updating your cMake install prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481958/setting-cmake-install-prefix-from-cmakelists-txt-file/39485990

Best!